# ¿Cómo usar una variable en una consulta sql en Python?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.7

Quiero saber como construir una consulta sql en la que el parámetro `where ='recurso'` sea la variable `recurso = soup.find('input', {'id': 'recurso'}).get('value')`

Lo que quiero es que el `select` obtenga los registros filtrado por la variable `recurso`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def obtieneDatos():

    global url 
    global contratista
    global recurso
    global vigencia

    if request.method == 'POST':
        
            url = request.form['scan']
           
            html = requests.get(url, verify=False)
            content = html.content
            soup = b(content, "lxml")

            contratista = soup.find('input', {'id': 'contratista'}).get('value')
            recurso = soup.find('input', {'id': 'recurso'}).get('value')
            vigencia = soup.find('input', {'id': 'vigencia'}).get('value')
            urlImagen = soup.find("img").get("src")
            urlImagen =  urlImagen.replace('amp;', '')

           
            contratista = contratista
            recurso = recurso
            vigencia = vigencia

            conexion_MySQLdb = connectionBD()
            cur = conexion_MySQLdb.cursor()
            
            cur.execute("""
                SELECT * FROM movingresos 
                INNER JOIN ingresos on movingresos.IdIngreso = ingresos.idIngreso
                WHERE ingresos.recurso = 'recurso'
                order by ingresos.recurso DESC , movingresos.estado DESC LIMIT 1;""")
             
            conexion_MySQLdb.commit()
            cur.close() #Cerrando conexion SQL
            conexion_MySQLdb.close() #cerrando conexion de la BD

            return render_template('public/dashboard/home.html', contratista = contratista, recurso = recurso, vigencia = vigencia, dataLogin = dataLoginSesion())
```

Intenté de la siguente manera pero me da error.

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) def obtieneDatos():

```
    global url 
    global contratista
    global recurso
    global vigencia

    if request.method == 'POST':
        
            url = request.form['scan']
           
            html = requests.get(url, verify=False)
            content = html.content
            soup = b(content, "lxml")

            contratista = soup.find('input', {'id': 'contratista'}).get('value')
            recurso = soup.find('input', {'id': 'recurso'}).get('value')
            vigencia = soup.find('input', {'id': 'vigencia'}).get('value')
            urlImagen = soup.find("img").get("src")
            urlImagen =  urlImagen.replace('amp;', '')
           
            contratista = contratista
            recurso = recurso
            vigencia = vigencia
            
            conexion_MySQLdb = connectionBD()
            cur = conexion_MySQLdb.cursor()
            
            sql=("""
                SELECT * FROM movingresos 
                INNER JOIN ingresos on movingresos.IdIngreso = ingresos.idIngreso
                WHERE ingresos.recurso =(s%)
                order by ingresos.recurso DESC , movingresos.estado DESC LIMIT 1;""")

            cur.execute(sql, recurso)

            conexion_MySQLdb.commit()
            cur.close() #Cerrando conexion SQL
            conexion_MySQLdb.close() #cerrando conexion de la BD

            return render_template('public/dashboard/home.html', contratista = contratista, recurso = recurso, vigencia = vigencia, dataLogin = dataLoginSesion())
```

ERROR

ProgrammingError
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: str(BATTAGLINO CARLOS), it must be of type list, tuple or dict

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Login flask mysql\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2548, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Login flask mysql\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Login flask mysql\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Login flask mysql\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Login flask mysql\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Login flask mysql\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
File "C:\Login flask mysql\app\app.py", line 214, in obtieneDatos
cur.execute(sql, recurso)
File "C:\Login flask mysql\env\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 562, in execute
raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: str(BATTAGLINO CARLOS), it must be of type list, tuple or dict
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! usando parametros (lo mejor) o concatenandolo en el string (no recomendado)

Comment: es sql o mysql ???

Comment: Es mysql, gracias por tu comentario

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 sql es una forma de referirse al lenguaje sql, no a un motor de base de datos. Se debe usar junto al motor de base de datos.

Comment: mysql tiene su propio motor de base de datos y es completamente distinto a sql y a mssql ... pregunto por que es importante usar la etiqueta adecuada a lo que esta haciendo el OP.

Comment: Lei mal la descripcion de la etiqueta. Perdon.

Answer (score 0):

Solución.
cur = conexion_MySQLdb.cursor(buffered=True)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def obtieneDatos():

```
    global url 
    global contratista
    global recurso
    global vigencia

    if request.method == 'POST':
        
            url = request.form['scan']
           
            html = requests.get(url, verify=False)
            content = html.content
            soup = b(content, "lxml")

            contratista = soup.find('input', {'id': 'contratista'}).get('value')
            recurso = soup.find('input', {'id': 'recurso'}).get('value')
            vigencia = soup.find('input', {'id': 'vigencia'}).get('value')
            urlImagen = soup.find("img").get("src")
            urlImagen =  urlImagen.replace('amp;', '')
           
            contratista = contratista
            recurso = recurso
            vigencia = vigencia
            urlCompleto = urlCompleto

            conexion_MySQLdb = connectionBD()
            cur = conexion_MySQLdb.cursor(buffered=True)
            
            print(recurso)

            cur.execute("""
                SELECT * FROM movingresos 
                INNER JOIN ingresos on movingresos.IdIngreso = ingresos.idIngreso
                WHERE ingresos.recurso = %s
                order by ingresos.recurso DESC , movingresos.estado DESC LIMIT 1;""",(recurso,))

            conexion_MySQLdb.commit()
            cur.close() #Cerrando conexion SQL
            conexion_MySQLdb.close() #cerrando conexion de la BD

            return render_template('public/dashboard/home.html', contratista = contratista, recurso = recurso, vigencia = vigencia, dataLogin = dataLoginSesion())
```

Comment: No olvides explicar el funcionamiento del código. Lee [answer] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).